# Spring - passing a custom instance to a constructor

Tags: java, spring, command-query-separation

I'm trying to implement a command-query design pattern into
a MVC spring based application.

I have, for example, some decorated commands using decorator pattern
like bellow:

```
ICommandHandler handler =
    new DeadlockRetryCommandHandlerDecorator<MoveCustomerCommand>(
        new TransactionCommandHandlerDecorator<MoveCustomerCommand>(
            new MoveCustomerCommandHandler(
                new EntityFrameworkUnitOfWork(connectionString),
                // Inject other dependencies for the handler here
            )
        )
    );
```

How can I inject such a handler into a controller constructor? Where should
I instantiate this handler? A place where this can be instantiated can be
the controller constructor, but this isn't the best solution. Any other ideeas?

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure what exactly do you want to achieve, but you look at bean factory methods maybe? You can inject needed dependencies into one bean that can be used as factory for your decorators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer (old) or PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer (new), and your connection string is in a .properties file or environment variable you can do the following for the connection string.  You can also autowire objects into a configuration class and annotate a method with @Bean to do what the Spring context xml does.  With this approach you can create your beans as you wish and they're available to autowire just like you defined them in xml.

```
@Configuration
public class MyAppConfig {

   @Autowired private MyType somethingToAutowire;

   @Bean
   public ICommandHandler iCommandHandler(@Value("${datasource.connectionString}") 
                                                  final String connectionString) {

       return new DeadlockRetryCommandHandlerDecorator<MoveCustomerCommand>();

       // You obviously have access to anything autowired in your configuration
       // class.  Then you can @Autowire a ICommandHandler type into one of your 
       // beans and this method will be called to create the ICommandHandler (depending on bean scope)

   }
}
```